# How can I add a valid provisioning profile to my MAUI project, in VS Code?

Tags: ios, visual-studio-code, maui

Using VS Code on an M1 Macbook pro, I'm trying to build a project, for a local physical device.
It fails with the error message:

*"Could not find any available provisioning profiles for My.Maui.App on iOS."*

How do I add a provisioning profile, and reference it, if that is needed?

EDIT:
On developer.apple.com, these are the 3 profiles that are available. None are in my keychain at this moment:
[image: An image of the profiles available]

Only the App Store profile is available for download.

Comment: Is the PP already in your Keychain?

Comment: Good comment. I have checked the profiles in my developer account, and updated my question.

Comment: There are two approaches to provisioning your iOS device: [Automatic provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=vs) and [Manual provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=vs), you can refer to the docs.